# How to make the webpage white until my string has been changed

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
(function($){
    'use strict';
    document.getElementByClass('Class').innerHTML = 'text'
})()
```

I need this code to be executed while the page is white (**page needs to be white before elements load in**) I need code that checks to see if the Classes text has been changed and then remove the code that makes the entire page white.

Comment: Couldn't you change the code after the new assignment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `loading` class that hides your elements while you render the page /re-load content, then remove it when done.

Here's an example that uses `visibility` with a `transition` - you could equally used `.loading { display:none; }` set the text+background to white to match original requirements.

```js
// Simulate loading
setTimeout(function() {
  $("#d1").text("loaded");
  $(".loading").removeClass("loading");
}, 1000);
```

```css
div.loading {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

div {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="d1" class='loading'>hidden during load</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton @freedomn-m it is most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Note, `.getElementByClass()` is not a `DOM` method. Since jQuery is being used

```
$(".Class").html("text")
```

or

```
$(".Class").text("text")
```

can be substituted.

To use [`.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) which returns an `HTMLCollection`,

if more than a single element is expected to be affected, you can iterate the collection

```
for (let i = 0, el = document.getElementsByClassName("class"); i < el.length; i++) {
  el[i].textContent = "text"
}
```

JavaScript solution

Select all elements, set `opacity` to `0`

```
$.holdReady(true);
$("*").css("opacity", 0);
// do stuff
$.holdReady(false);
$(function() {
  $("*").css("opacity", 1);
  // do stuff
})
```

Ideally `opacity` can be set at CSS to avoid flicker or flash of the `document` being displayed before JavaScript is executed

```
* {opacity: 0}
```

the use `$.holdReady(true)` to perform evaluation while holding `jQuery()` being executed, once evaluation is complete execute `jQuery.holdReady(false)` and set `opacity` to `1`.

Comment: Yeah alright that will make the entire page white but how about changing all the elements back to normal after the string has been changed?

Comment: @TravisScott Reverse the procedure `$("*").css("opacity", 1)`